# CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid with playfabserver

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, mesh

I convert mesh to binary 
I encrypted it with Key,Iv and upload file

I downloaded it from the playfabserver, decrypted  and then converted the binary file into a mesh file

This error occurs in Decryption
CryptographicException: The length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

Is this a loss from sending to the server?

here encrypt source 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5719/Simple-encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-C

Of course, it was successful to encrypt and decrypt mesh files without server.

upload download is active  Without difficulty

```
public void Upload()
    {
        keyName = inputField.text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyName)&&scirptCamCon.TargetObj1)
        {
            Byte[] by = ReturnMesh();
            Byte[] mIv = Encrpyt.GetIv();
            Byte[] mKey = Encrpyt.GetKey();

            Byte[] Encrtpted = EncDec.Encrypt(by, mIv, mKey);
            PlayFabServerAPI.SetTitleData( new PlayFab.ServerModels.SetTitleDataRequest
            {
                  Key = keyName+"2",
                  Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mKey)
            },
              Onsuccess => { Debug.Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mKey)); },
              Onfail => { Onfail.GenerateErrorReport(); }
            );

            PlayFabServerAPI.SetTitleInternalData(new PlayFab.ServerModels.SetTitleDataRequest
            {
                Key = keyName + "1",
                Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mIv)
            },
              Onsuccess => { Debug.Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mIv)); },
              Onfail => { Onfail.GenerateErrorReport(); }
            );
            UploadFileToCDN(keyName, by);
            inputField.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }   


    public void UploadFileToCDN(string key, byte[] content, string contentType = "binary/octet-stream")
    {
        GetUploadUrl(key, contentType, presignedUrl =>
        {
           PutFile(presignedUrl, content);
        });
    }

    void GetUploadUrl(string key, string contentType, Action<string> onComplete)
    {
        PlayFabAdminAPI.GetContentUploadUrl(new GetContentUploadUrlRequest()
        {
            ContentType = contentType,
            Key = key
        }, result => onComplete(result.URL),
        error => Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport()));
    }

    public void PutFile(string putURL, byte[] payload)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(putURL);
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";

        if (payload != null)
        {
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(string.Format("ERROR: Byte arrry was empty or null"));
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("Starting HTTP PUT...");  
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Debug.Log("...HTTP PUT Successful");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(string.Format("ERROR: [{0}] -- {1}", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription));
        }
    }

    public void DownloadFileFromCDN(string key)
    {
        GetDownloadUrl(key, presignedUrl =>
        {
            GetFile(presignedUrl);
        });
    }

    void GetDownloadUrl(string key, Action<string> onComplete)
    {
        if(scirptCamCon.TargetObj1)
        scirptCamCon.TargetObj1.name = key;
        PlayFabClientAPI.GetContentDownloadUrl(new GetContentDownloadUrlRequest()
        {
            Key = key,
            ThruCDN = true 
        }, result => onComplete(result.URL),
        error => Debug.LogError(error.GenerateErrorReport()));
    }

    void GetFile(string preauthorizedUrl)
    {
        StartCoroutine(FileRecevier(preauthorizedUrl));
    }

    IEnumerator FileRecevier(string preauthorizedUrl)
    {
        string keyVale = keyName + "2";
        string ivVale = keyName + "1";
        byte[] thisiv=new byte[16];
        byte[] thiskey= new byte[16];
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(preauthorizedUrl);
        PlayFabServerAPI.GetTitleData(new PlayFab.ServerModels.GetTitleDataRequest(),
       result => {
           if (result.Data == null || !result.Data.ContainsKey(keyVale)) Debug.Log("No key");
           else Debug.Log("KeyValue: " + result.Data[keyVale]);
           thiskey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.Data[keyVale]);
       },                   //키값을 출력하는 방법이 result.data[keyname]을 
       error => {
           Debug.Log("Got error getting titleData:");
           Debug.Log(error.GenerateErrorReport());
       }
        );
        PlayFabServerAPI.GetTitleInternalData(new PlayFab.ServerModels.GetTitleDataRequest(),
        result => {
            if (result.Data == null || !result.Data.ContainsKey(ivVale)) Debug.Log("No value");
            else Debug.Log("ivVale: " + result.Data[ivVale]);
            thisiv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.Data[ivVale]);
        },
        error => {
            Debug.Log("Got error getting titleData:");
            Debug.Log(error.GenerateErrorReport());
        }
    );
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("SucessfulDownload");
            results = www.downloadHandler.data;
            if (scirptCamCon.TargetObj1)
            {
                Debug.Log(thiskey.Length);
                Debug.Log(thisiv.Length);
                DestroyImmediate(scirptCamCon.TargetObj1.GetComponent<MeshCollider>());
                results = EncDec.Decrypt(results, thiskey, thisiv);
                MeshSerializer.DeserializeMesh(results, scirptCamCon.TargetObj1.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh);
                scirptCamCon.TargetObj1.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();

            }
            else
                Debug.Log("Null obj.");
        }
    }
```

CryptographicException: The length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

Comment: Have you verified that the file you download is identical to the original one you encrypted locally? If it is not, determine whether it is the upload or the download that is corrupting the file. It sounds from your description that this is not a cryptographic problem, so you may want to edit the question after figuring that out so it doesn't get flagged as a possible duplicate.

Comment: @ColinYoung  I check this problem Unfortunately Encryption file and key and iv is same   this code //  if (results.SequenceEqual(Encrtpted)) also key and iv Not this result is true  . Is SequenceEqual incorrect???

Comment: @ColinYoung I attempt this problems

Comment: @ColinYoung problem is encryption error Previous test is tested one function but other  function call is occured error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use same key,same iv,same data
Miraculously result is diffrence of original

to server file is convert it is very werid